# Opening and closing Bootstrap dropdown without clicking via JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap dropdown like the snippet below for my sites mini cart. I set it up so that when it drops down there is a lightbox effect behind it that greys out the rest of the content.

```js
$(".dropdown").on('show.bs.dropdown hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
  if(e.type == 'hide'){
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
  }else if(e.type == 'show'){
    lightbox.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
#lightbox_container{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:40;
  display:none;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown d-inline minicart">
  <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="media/icons/cart.png" alt="cart icon" class="icon">
  </span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="minicart">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    // stuff goes here
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="lightbox_container"></div>
```

This works as expected and is working fine but I want to pop up the minicart when something gets added.

I'm new to Bootstrap so not really sure how I can achieve this. I did this:

```
function show_cart(){
    $(".minicart").addClass("show");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").addClass("show");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("position", "absolute");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("transform", "translate3d(-171px, 21px, 0px)");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("top", "0px");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("left", "0px");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("will-change", "transform");
    $("#lightbox_container").css("display", "block");
}
```

But obviously this isn't great, even though it kind of works, but when it opens out I can't click outside the dropdown to close it I actually have to go up and click on the icon.

### Edit

I changed it to:

```
function show_cart(){
    $(".minicart").addClass("show");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").addClass("show");;
    var doc_width = $(document).outerWidth(true);
    if (doc_width <= 768){
        $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("left", "-250px");
    }else{
        $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").css("left", "-350px");
    }
    $("#lightbox_container").css("display", "block");
}
```

And then to hide it again I added an on click event to the actual lightbox:

```
$("#lightbox_container").on("click", function(){
    if($("#navbarSupportedContent").hasClass("show")){
        $("#navbarSupportedContent").hide();
    }
    if($(".dropdown.locale").hasClass("show")){
        $(".dropdown.locale").hide();
    }
    if($(".dropdown.minicart").hasClass("show")){
        $(".dropdown.minicart").hide();
    }
    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox_container");
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
    $(".minicart .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "flase");
    $(".minicart .dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may toggle visibility directly on menu, like this:

```
$('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

Or like this:

```
$('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').show();
```

If you want you may also simulate the click on toggle button:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, toggle or show will both show the dropdown but it will be styled incorrectly and without the lightbox and I am unable to click off of it to close it again. Then when I do click the icon to as if to close it, it acts like it is being toggled again for the first time and displays properly with the lightbox effect and clicking again will hide the lightbox and keep the dropdown on screen